# count repeated array of object property to produce a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have this array of object

```
[{
    tag: 'james'
  },
  {
    tag: 'james'
  },
  {
    tag: 'john'
  }
]
```

How do I count and produce a new array like below?

```
[{
  tag: 'james',
  count: 2
}, {
  tag: 'john',
  count: 1
}]
```

my attempt using reduce produced object not array of object.

```js
const arr = [{tag: 'james'},{tag: 'james'},{tag: 'john'}];
let newArr = arr.reduce((accum, arr) => {
  accum[arr.tag] = ++accum[arr.tag] || 1
  return accum
}, {})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an object instead of a number and finally get those values from object using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method.

```
// just extract values from the object as an array
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((accum, o) => {
  // initialize object if not defined already
  accum[o.tag] = accum[o.tag] || { ...o, count: 0  }
  // increment count property
  accum[o.tag].count++;
  return accum
}, {}))
```

```js
let arr = [{tag: 'james'},{tag: 'james'},{tag: 'john'}]

let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((accum, o) => {
  accum[o.tag] = accum[o.tag] || { ...o, count: 0 }
  accum[o.tag].count++;
  return accum
}, {}))

console.log(res)
```

---

You can even create the array directly by using an additional variable for object/index referencing.

```
// an object for keeping reference 
let ref = {};

let res = arr.reduce((accum, o) => {
  // check reference already defined, if not define refernece and push to the array
  ref[o.tag] || accum.push(ref[o.tag] = { ...o, count: 0 })
  // update count using the refernece keeped in the object
  ref[o.tag].count++;
  return accum
}, []);
```

```js
let arr = [{tag: 'james'},{tag: 'james'},{tag: 'john'}]

let ref = {};

let res = arr.reduce((accum, o) => {
  ref[o.tag] || accum.push(ref[o.tag] = { ...o, count: 0 })
  ref[o.tag].count++;
  return accum
}, []);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were nearly there, but you need to take the key and value out of the object and build a new array.

```js
var array = [{ tag: 'jane' }, { tag: 'jane' }, { tag: 'john' }],
    result = Object
        .entries(
            array.reduce((accum, { tag }) => {
                accum[tag] = (accum[tag] || 0) + 1;
                return accum;
            }, {}))
        .map(([tag, count]) => ({ tag, count }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why the map? The one from Balan seems simpler `let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((accum, o) => {
  accum[o.tag] = accum[o.tag] || { ...o,
    count: 0
  }
  accum[o.tag].count++;
  return accum
}, {}))`

Comment: my solution keeps the overhead small (and abstract) and builds a final object, where the metioned code build directly the final object as value of the object. it looks like a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

First test if the object does not exist - if it doesn't, create one. Then add to the accumulator. Also note you want an array, so use `[]` not `{}` for the accumulator value:

```js
const data = [{
    tag: 'james'
  },
  {
    tag: 'james'
  },
  {
    tag: 'john'
  }
];

const grouped = data.reduce((acc, { tag }) => {
  if (!acc.some(e => e.tag == tag)) {
    acc.push({ tag, count: 0 });
  }
  acc.find(e => e.tag == tag).count++;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler code would be:

```js
const arr = [{
    tag: 'james'
  },
  {
    tag: 'james'
  },
  {
    tag: 'john'
  },
  {
    tag: 'lewis'
  },
  {
    tag: 'john'
  }
]

const counts = arr.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  const val = acc.find(t => t.tag == cv.tag)
  if (val) {
    val.count++
    acc.push(val)
    return acc
  }
  cv.count = 1
  acc.push(cv)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition was good and you were quite close; I propose you a bit more generic answer

```
const groupTags = data => field => Object.values(data.reduce((acc, o) =>
({...acc,
  [o[field]]: {
    [field]: o[field],
    count: acc[o[field]] ? acc[o[field]].count + 1 : 1 
  }
}), {}))
```

You can use it like

```
groupTags(data)("tag")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//simple approach using forEach method

let lists = [{tag: 'james'},{tag: 'james'},{tag: 'john'}]; 
const finalOutput = [];
const tempStore = {};

lists.forEach((list) => {
      tempStore[list.tag] = (tempStore[list.tag] == undefined) ? 1: tempStore[list.tag]+1;
      const index = finalOutput.findIndex(e => e.tag == list.tag);
      if(index > -1) {
        finalOutput[index] = {tag: list.tag, count: tempStore[list.tag]}
      }
      else 
        finalOutput.push({tag: list.tag, count: tempStore[list.tag]})
});

console.log(finalOutput);
```